# not able to increase width of UILabel in landscape mode

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview, uilabel

I had made an iPad application, in that I  have tableView whose name is crollTableView, in my tableView I am creating two labels in each cell of row, whose name is capitalLabel and stateLabel, in portrait mode,

now I want to increase width of my labels in landscape mode,

here is code snippet,

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if(tableView==crollTableView){
        static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell";
        static NSInteger StateTag = 1;
        static NSInteger CapitalTag = 2;
        UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if(cell == nil){

            // cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
            cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];
            CGRect frame;
            frame.origin.x = 0; 
            frame.origin.y = 0;
            frame.size.height = 70;
            frame.size.width = 650;


            UILabel *capitalLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
            capitalLabel.tag = CapitalTag;
            capitalLabel.opaque = FALSE;
            capitalLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:capitalLabel];


            frame.origin.x += 680;
            UILabel *stateLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
            stateLabel.tag = StateTag;
            stateLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:stateLabel];
        }  

        UILabel* capitalLabel = (UILabel *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:CapitalTag];
        UILabel*  stateLabel = (UILabel *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:StateTag];

        capitalLabel.text=[news2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        stateLabel.text = [news3 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

       capitalLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        stateLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        capitalLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        stateLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

        if(count<[news3 count]){
             capitalLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
            [capitalLabel sizeToFit];

            stateLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
            [stateLabel sizeToFit];

        }count++;

        return cell;
    }
 }
```

what changes should I do in my code ?

Comment: you have to check first orientation and after that you have to set the size of label according to your orientation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
 // Return YES for supported orientations.
 return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
 }
```

By checking the condition whether the current orientation is landscape or portrait you can set the frame of labels accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `autoresizingMask` to views that you want to automatically scale:

In  `if (cell == nil)` after `alloc+init` of labels add:

```
capitalLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;

stateLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```

Answer (score 1):

in iOS dont care about increase the width for the any control when change the orientation .. just set the autoresizing mask property for the 2 lables to be **UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth**  .. that means the width of your control will change according to the superview frame size.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Set `autoResizingMask` so that view will automatically adjust itself during orientation change.

You can change the value in `Xcode` size inspector.

[image]